# Issues with building up an experience buffer in Pytorch due to "inplace operation"

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, backpropagation

I am playing around with Pytorch after I have created reinforcement learning models mostly in Tensorflow so far. Now I am encountering issues when I want to integrate an "Experience Buffer" aka "Replay Buffer" into my otherwise neatly functioning code. I have build up a simple working example of my issue in the hope that one of you can provide me with an explanation what I am missing / not fully understand in Pytorch and how I can resolve that issue:

I use the OpenAi Gym Cart Pole environment to illustrate my problem.

```
# Load Dependencies
import gym
import numpy as np
import torch as t
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as f
import collections

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")  # Create the environment
buffer_cap = 100

class Network(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        self.dense1 = nn.Linear(4, 128)
        self.action = nn.Linear(128, 2)
        self.critic = nn.Linear(128, 1)        
        
     
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = f.relu(x)
        act = self.action(x)
        act = f.softmax(act, dim = 0)
        crt = self.critic(x)        
        return act, crt 
    
    def ActorLoss(self,log_prob, ret, value):
        ret = ret.unsqueeze(0)
        diff = ret - value
        return - log_prob * diff


#Experience Buffer
class ExpBuffer:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=capacity)

    def append(self, experience):
        self.buffer.append(experience)
        
    def __len__(self): #function that we can call "len()" of the instance
        return len(self.buffer)

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        #select multiple experiences to form an uncorrelated batch
        indices = np.random.choice(len(self.buffer), batch_size, replace = False) 
        #zip(*zipped) unzippes a zipped input
        log_probs, values, rewards = zip(*[self.buffer[idx] for idx in indices])
        return zip(log_probs, values, rewards)


class Worker():
    
    def __init__(self):        

        self.net = Network() 
        self.optimizer = t.optim.Adam(self.net.parameters(), lr = 0.02)
        self.ExpBuffer  = ExpBuffer(buffer_cap)         
        self.Experience = collections.namedtuple('Experience', "log_probs value reward")   
        
    def fillExperience(self):
        #Fill up experience buffer until cap is reached
        
        while len(self.ExpBuffer) < buffer_cap:
            action_probs_hist = []  
            critic_value_hist = []
            rewards_hist = []
            state_next = env.reset()
            done = False    
            while not done:            
    
                state = t.tensor(state_next, dtype = t.float) #convert numpy output to tensor
                action_probs, critic_value = self.net.forward(state)
                action = t.multinomial(action_probs,1) #Select action with given probability
                state_next, reward, done, _ = env.step(int(action)) #next step
          
                action_probs_hist.append(action_probs[action])
                critic_value_hist.append(critic_value)
                rewards_hist.append(reward)

            #Fill up experience buffer
            for log_prob, val,rew in zip(action_probs_hist,critic_value_hist,rewards_hist) :
                exp = self.Experience(log_prob, val, rew)
                self.ExpBuffer.append(exp)
            
    def train(self):
        #Training shall be nothing else in that exanmple
        #than sampling twice from the batch and backpropagate
        
   
        for i in range(2): #Simply sample two times and backpropagate
            loss =  []
            batch = self.ExpBuffer.sample(5)            
                    
            for log_prob, val, ret in batch:
                loss.append(self.net.ActorLoss(log_prob, val, ret))
       
            # Backpropagation   steps              
            loss_value = sum(loss)            
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()            
            loss_value.backward()            
            self.optimizer.step()
                
if __name__ == "__main__":

    w = Worker()
    w.fillExperience()
    w.train()
```

So the steps are:

- Create a worker that initializes a network, an optimizer and an Experience Buffer
- Fill that Buffer with Experiences by using collections
- The "Training" is simply the sampling of the experiences two times.

In the actual code the network is updated and new experiences are created and stored.

In the second sampling round, when I reach `loss.backward()` I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [128, 1]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

I already applied `t.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)` to at least get a bit more information, but it did not help. I tried to google and understand it but I don't.

Would anybody shine some light on this issue. What is going on under the hood and what can I do to solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

KO4all
I experienced the same problem like you.
My error is because (I guess from now) I introduce LSTM into a worked PPO-continued algorithm.
I have an operation like your code :

> log_probs, values, rewards = zip(*[self.buffer[idx] for idx in indices])

For me, I use for-loop to continueously calculate value. But I dont know how to fix it.
I hope someone could help you out, maybe that solution also works for me.